# rsync Not Immediately Showing Progress

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run a `rsync` command on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine to transfer some files to a WSL1 system running on a Windows 10 machine, the transfer progress is not always shown immediately despite using the `-P`.

```
rsync --bwlimit=200000 --remove-source-files -P /data/*.dat rsync://elonmusk@192.168.1.2:12000/data
```

It sometimes takes about 5 minutes before showing the progress details

```
382abd067bf4bddc701db2dc8da67656368b7a6b58f6abd60cfada3e3499ca6f.dat
 78,138,310,656  71%  292.50MB/s    0:01:42
```

Is there a way to force `rsync` to always show the progress soon after starting the transfer? Using `rsync` version 3.1.3 on the Ubuntu system.

Comment: If you make a "normal" `ssh` connection to the WSL instance, does it connect immediately or have similar delay?  Also try increasing verbosity on both `rsync` and `ssh` and add anything relevant to the question.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Making a regular ssh connection to the WSL instance takes 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you're copying files with a name matching files on the destination. In this instance the delay is related to `rsync` checksumming the source and destination to see what, if anything, has changed. The progress indicator shows the transfer of data.

If you include timestamps in the copy you may find that `rsync` doesn't need to perform the copy at all. (Unless the data has changed, of course).

```
rsync --bwlimit=200000 --remove-source-files -tP /data/*.dat rsync://elonmusk@192.168.1.2:12000/data/
```